# I am trying to use download and use pygal to learn data science visualization

Tags: import, data-science, python-3.7, linux-mint, pygal

I am not able to run pygal from my linux mint set up. I am using an example from Eric Matthes, Python Crash Course Chapter 15 on histograms. I have the die_visual.svg saved to a file but when I try and open it up in the web browser I get the error: 
'''
XML Parsing Error: syntax error
Location: file:///home/jubal/%20CrashCourse%20Python%20Notes/data_science/die_visual.svg
Line Number 1, Column 1:
import pygal
^
'''

I am a linux mint user and definitely a newbie when it comes to installing and operating certain programs with mint, but am trying to learn. Any help would be appreciated, thanks for your time.

```
import pygal
from die import Die

# create a D6

die = Die()


# make some rolls and store results in list
results = []

for roll_num in range(100):
    result = die.roll()
    results.append(result)

frequencies = []
for value in range(1, die.num_sides+1):
    frequency = results.count(value)
    frequencies.append(frequency)
# visualize the results
hist = pygal.Bar()

hist.x_labels = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
hist.x_title = 'Result'
hist.y_title = 'Frequency of Result'

hist.add('D6', frequencies)
hist.render_to_file('die_visual.svg')


#print(frequencies)    

#print(results)
```

Comment: It looks like you saved this file as die_visual.svg. You are supposed to save this with a .py ending, run the file, and running it will generate an .svg file that you can view in the browser.

Comment: I have it saved at die_visual.py in my file, not svg. /home/jubal/ CrashCourse Python Notes/data_science/die_visual.py

Comment: How are you running the file? Do you get any output when you run the .py file? That error really looks like your browser is trying to read the .py file. I just ran your code with my own copy of die.py, and I get the graph as the output. If you open your .svg file in a text editor, what are the first couple lines?

Comment: So it will work with the Spyder ide, but doesnt work when I run it with VS code. Definitely dont mind using Spyder, but I would like to stay with VS code if at all possible. Do you know of a way that will allow me to run the code in VS? Thanks for your time!

Comment: What output do you get when you run this with VS Code? This code generates a .svg file. The act of viewing that file is separate from the act of creating the file.

Comment: $ python "/home/jubal/ CrashCourse Python Notes/data_science/die_visual.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jubal/ CrashCourse Python Notes/data_science/die_visual.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygal 
ImportError: No module named pygal

Comment: That means the version of Python that VSCode is pointing to doesn't have pygal installed. I believe Spyder creates its own environment, so when you installed pygal using Spyder you only installed it to the environment that Spyder uses. If you install pygal in the same terminal you referenced in the previous comment with `python -m pip install --user pygal`, then execute the file, I think your program might run.

Comment: $ python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> python -m pip install --user pygal
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python -m pip install --user pygal
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: This was the error I ran into. I am able to run it through the jupyter notebook environment on VS code, which helps, but still cannot get the code to run in terminal.

Comment: Wow i just got it, had to update python to a newer version and die_visual.svg showed up in the correct file. Thanks for the help, most importantly i appreciate your time.